# Verify condition was satisfied on scroll, then run a function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code that runs a counter, counting up from 0 to a figure defined by the text inside the HTML tag. This works fine - I have four elements using the class and each will count up from 0 when the page is loaded.

But where it got tricky is that I want the respective counters to begin as each element comes into view.

What I found was that the counter kept re-starting as I scrolled. I've tried using the jQuery `.one()` method attached to the `.scroll()` event handler but I need to continually check that the condition has been satisfied with regards the element being visible, and this is where I've come unstuck.

Here's what I have:

```
$(window).on('scroll',function(e) {
    $('.count').each(function(i) {      
        var topOfElement = $(this).offset().top;
        var bottomOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (bottomOfWindow > topOfElement) {
            $(window).one('scroll',function(e) {    
                $(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                    Counter: $(this).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (now) {
                        $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

And the simple HTML:

```
<span class="count">4143</span>
<span class="count">920</span>
<span class="count">5112</span>
<span class="count">76</span>
```

I'm getting a "Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined" error.

Comment: `$(this).prop('Counter',0).animate({` <-- what do you think `this` is? It is not a ".count" element

Comment: Hi. I thought that was defined by $('.count').each(function(i) { but I guess nesting the event handler has broken it?

Comment: It is window since you are binding the event to window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As epascarello pointed out, you were re-binding the .scroll event on each .scroll event. You only need one binding.

But you also needed a way to identify that the count-up process had fired, and that it need not be run again. Simple way to do that is to add a class to the element.

I also didn't see how you were getting the maxcount value from the span tag.

```js
$(window).on('scroll',function(e) {
    $('.count').each(function(i, e) {      
        var topOfElement = $(e).offset().top;
        var bottomOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        if (bottomOfWindow > (topOfElement + 80)) {
        //debugger;
            if ( !$(e).hasClass('done') ){
                $(e).addClass('done');
                
                let maxcnt = $(e).text();
                maxcnt = parseInt(maxcnt);
                $(e).prop('Counter',0).animate({
                    Counter: $(e).text()
                }, {
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function (maxcnt) {
                        $(e).text(Math.ceil(maxcnt));
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
div{height:250px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<span class="count">4143</span>
<div></div>
<span class="count">920</span>
<div></div>
<span class="count">5112</span>
<div></div>
<span class="count">76</span>
<div></div>
```

Comment: @ColossalYouth Yes, a global variable is a good way to solve this, as is adding a class. Glad you solved it.

Comment: Thanks - very similar to what I came up with but using a variable instead of the class. Out of interest, what's the purpose of maxcnt? I didn't need it but now I'm wondering why.

Comment: MaxCnt is the value grabbed from each span (the text in that span) - so that when the counter reaches that number (different for each span), counting stops for that span. I wasn't sure how you got that number in your question sample code, but I deduced that requirement from the question information. You had `now` as the max value to which any span would count, but I didn't see where that was defined.

Comment: BTW, the nice advantage to using a class rather than a global var is that the global variable need not be pre-defined (the className is more dynamic/flexible). I also figured that we would need one global var for each counter (if we wanted the counting to be able to overlap - i.e. two could be counting at once), and using a class resolved that need also.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for this, it's been really useful. I've switched to your approach with classes for that very reason - now that I'm applying this to all four elements it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside the one scroll is the window element.

```
$('.count').each(function(i) {      
  var elem = $(this);
  ...
  if (bottomOfWindow > topOfElement) {
    $(window).one('scroll',function(e) {
      $(elem).prop('Counter',0).animate({
        ...
```

Comment: Will `window.scroll()` continue to fire, or will `.one()` remove the event handler after the first event? https://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Thanks, not sure how I missed that. So I fixed that and believe I've come up against the issue @gibberish mentions which is the crux really - the counter is now counting up and down as I scroll, so presumably it's firing repeatedly.

Comment: Well what you are doing makes little sense since every time you scroll you are binding scroll to all the elements. Scroll fires a bunch of times so you are binding tons of events to the elements. No clue what you are actually trying to do and that seems to be a different question.

Comment: I thought it was clear, apologies. I have four elements that I want to count up from 0 as each becomes visible on the page, but as per the question title, to do that successful I need to keep checking the condition is satisfied on scroll while only firing the counter for each element once.

Comment: Problem is you bind the event everytime the check is true. It fires once, but the next time, the window.onscroll fires you bind it again

Comment: I've searched to find a way to do the if statement on scroll and once the condition's satisfied, stop there, but no luck. I'd actually be happy enough for all four elements to count simultaneously once the first is visible in the viewport, as they're on the same row in desktop.

Comment: So why are you binding onscroll on the element? Just set a flag once it was been increased and ignore it.

Comment: Thanks, I've no idea why I didn't think of that. I used a flag and it's working fine. It may be obvious that I'm no coder - to make this work I had to learn how to update a global variable as I had no idea about global and local scope until now.